# Testing for an empty xml file in Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have Python script to parse XML files into a more friendly format for another platform.

Every so often one of the data files contains no data - only the encoding info and no other tags, which is causing ElementTree to throw a ParseError when it finds them.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Is there a way of testing for the empty file before calling ElementTree?

Ta.

Comment: maybe count the `<` character in data? if you find just 1 then file is probably empty.

Comment: Err, how about `endswith("?>")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course have several ways, use:

```
try:
    pass # delete this and add your parse code
except:
    pass # write your exception when empty
```

or use if statement:

```
if (some code to evalue if xml is not empty):
    # your code
elif (some code to check if .xml is empty):
    # your code
```

let me know how it was!

Comment: Thank you - try/catch was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: please if my answer was helpful in some way, vote for it!
:)

Comment: I did - apparently I don't have enough points for it to count yet, sorry ;(

Answer (score 2):

You should **ask for forgiveness not permission** here.

Handle the exception by wrapping the code in a `try/except` block.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
...
try:    
   tree = ET.parse(fooxml)
except ET.ParseError:
   # log error
   pass
```

Comment: Thank you - this looks perfect. I have other coding experience but my Python knowledge is somewhat less than 8 hours old and I have to do this in a hurry ;)

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could catch the exception that `lxml` throws. If you want to avoid parsing, you could check if the file contains only one `<` symbol:

```
with open("input.xml","rb") as f:
   contents = f.read()
   if contents.count(b"<")<=1:
      # empty or only header: skip
      pass
   else:
      x = etree.XML(contents)
```

of course this heuristic method doesn't protect from other parsing errors. So it's best to just protect the parsing by a `try/except` block.

But this method has the advantage of being extremely fast if you have lots of corrupt 1-line "header only" file.